# Javascript slider through array elements

Tags: javascript, html, slider

Actually next() and previous() buttons are not working like they should be, means if second element is displayed by next button then then after clicking previous button the first element has to be shown but it starts from the end .
One more problem is that after using setTimeout() function, when i click on next it accelerate the speed of timer as it should have same speed for auto play which is given.

```js
var newsArr = ["my name is nouman", "i live in abbottabad", "the breaking news about Pakistan"];
var i = 1;
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function next() {
  if (i < newsArr.length) {
    x.innerHTML = newsArr[i];
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
    x.innerHTML = newsArr[i];
  }
  setTimeout(next, 2000);
}

function prev() {
  if (i >= 0) {
    x.innerHTML = newsArr[i];
    i--;
  } else {
    i = newsArr.length - 1;
    x.innerHTML = newsArr[i];
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="newsslider">
  <p class="text" id="demo">my name is nouman </p>
  <button class="btn1" type="button" class="prev" onclick="prev()">PREV</button>
  <button class="btn2" type="button" class="next" onclick="next()">NEXT</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Next() and prev() functions are not working properly ,

Comment: That's not a question. That's a statement.

Comment: What i should do so that the Next() and prev() functions may work properly?

Comment: - What do you expect by clicking on next?
- What do you expect by clicking on prev?

Comment: What is the desired functionality? Because we cant possibly know what "work properly" means.

Comment: I think you need to show one message from the array at a time on button click. remove `setTimeout()`

Comment: yes exactly but on same time i want to make it autoplay like slider

Comment: @Federico as i have three messages (elements )in an Array . by clicking i want to display them one by one and by prev() i want then to be display backward .

Comment: call next() in  `setInterval` to start slider and stop next() in `clearInterval` to stop it to mimic autoplay @NoumanArif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can guess what you want:

Every time you call the next function a new timeout start. Means that if you click on next for 3 times. You will have 3 timeouts running at the same time. That's way you see it accelerate.

The solution is to clear the running [timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) before to set a new one. This way you will always have at most one timeout running.

Also you might wanna first update the index and then adjust it if not valid. Otherwise you might end up in weird situations where you have `i > arr.length`.

```js
var newsArr = [
  "my name is nouman",
  "i live in abbottabad",
  "the breaking news about Pakistan",
];
var i = 0;
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var timeoutId;
function next() {
  if (timeoutId) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }
  i++;
  if (i < newsArr.length) {
    x.innerHTML = newsArr[i];
  } else {
    i = 0;
    x.innerHTML = newsArr[i];
  }
  timeoutId = setTimeout(next, 2000);
}

function prev() {
  i--;
  if (i >= 0) {
    x.innerHTML = newsArr[i];
  } else {
    i = newsArr.length - 1;
    x.innerHTML = newsArr[i];
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="newsslider">
  <p class="text" id="demo">my name is nouman </p>
  <button class="btn1" type="button" class="prev" onclick="prev()">PREV</button>
  <button class="btn2" type="button" class="next" onclick="next()">NEXT</button>
</div>
```